# log into app and run it on iPhone from iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, remote-control

Is it possible to use an iPad to link to an iPhone, remotely log into an app (saved on iPhone) and run it?  Can it be replicated across 20 different iPhones?

Skill Development App on iPhone tracks/records a player's attempt at mirroring a set of actions shown in a video launched by the app.  player has to be able to log into app which pulls up their specifically assigned, skill videos, then log out when done, but I don't want the player (typically a 5-10 yr old) having to pick up, move or otherwise reposition the iPhone.  Having a central iPad with which they can select an 'open' iPhone, log into the app, the move in front of that iPhone to begin training would be ideal and limit interactions to just the central iPad which can be "bolted down".

Comment: Do they have a compatible iPad app? That may be your best bet.

Comment: yes I should be able to load same app on ipad; however, if I'm trying to have 20 of these stations running different skill videos/recordings at the same time (tailored to the player);  I cannot see having 20 of the same app running on the central unit

Comment: It's really up to the app itself and how it's coded.  Natively, neither the iPad nor iPhone supports what you want to do.  A developer could code a app that you run on your iPad and then allow other iOS devices to log into that app (probably on a server in the cloud) and then stream videos from there.  I don't know of any app that does this, though.